# Confusion with node.js get/post and trying to make a new page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, pug

I have been searching for how to do this all evening but I don't know which terms exactly to search for so that is setting me back quite a bit...

I am trying to make a page called '/editor' in my node.js application.  I have created a button on my index page that I would like to redirect me to /editor.  I have made a editor.jade file as well, but I'm not sure how to navigate to it.

in app.js I have:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/game', routes.game);
app.get('/getContents', routes.getContents);
app.get('/editor', routes.editor);
app.post('/start', routes.start);
app.post('/quit', routes.quit);
app.post('/doAction', routes.doAction);
```

Should this even be a get?  Or am I getting confused and it should actually be a post?

In index.js I have:

```
function editor(req, res){
    console.log("Hey Sarah!");
    if(req.session.editor){
        console.log("Hey Sarah!");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Do you eve know what you're doing?");
    }
}
exports.editor = editor;
```

and in index.jade I have:

```
  div.well
    p Adventure Game Editor
    div
      form(action="/editor". method="post")
         div.control-group.input-append
         button(type ="editor") Editor
```

Right now clicking the button just redirects me to /post? which displays Cannot GET /post? and in the console GET /post? 404 2ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glancing through, it looks like your `form(action="/editor". method="post")` has a period rather than a comma (they look so similar and act so different).  I'm not sure what jade will do with that, but that might be the cause of your errors.  You'll also need an `app.post("/editor", FUNC_HERE)` line if you want the posted form to go anywhere.  And I would change the button to read `button(type="submit")` as `editor` is not a valid html button type.

Comment: Thank you, I have spent so long looking at the code that nothing is making sense any more

Comment: You're very welcome; I've been there myself.  Normally that's my cue to get away from it for a while and clear my head, but sometimes I just can't let it go.  Glad I could help!